# Padded data in CNN model (pytorch)

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, padding, masking

I have a simple CNN model built using pytorch. The input to the model is a matrix with shape [10,100]. The matrix values are generally only [0,1], apart from one exception. Because not all input matrices have the same length, whenever the matrix length is less than 100, it is padded with neutral values for the entire columns on each side. So for example if the input matrix shape is [10,90] it will be padded with 5 columns on each side with neutral values filling all of the cells of the padded columns. One more thing - for all non-padded columns there is exactly one cell with value 1 and the rest are zeros.

The problem is that while in my training and validation datasets, median length of the input is quite similar, e.g. 5 padded columns on each side, when evaluated with matrices with no padding at all (e.g. input with (10,100) shape) or very little, (e.g. (10,98)) the model seems to fail.

Given the consistent model's good performance on samples with padding vs without padding, I believe that the model is learning the padding patterns which is not great. I've tried to account for padding in the loss function by masking but it didn't seem to help much. Are there any other ways of addressing this? There is not much I can do in terms of data augmentation in this space so this is not really a good option.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason to always pad symmetrically? Can you pad by different amounts on the left and on the right? Also, instead of padding, can you just interleave neutral vectors at random locations in the matrix?

Comment: @YakovDan I don't really have to pad symmetrically. There could be arguments for left only/right only/both sides depending on the model I"m using, but lets say it's not mandatory, how does it help?

Comment: Well, if you think your model learns the padding patterns, make those padding more complicated and uncorrelated with the output. If it makes sense, I'd go with inserting columns at random locations, of which asymmetric padding is an instance

Comment: Also, if it makes sense in your setting, you could consider augmenting your data by dropping some percentage of not neutral columns and replacing those with neutrals, provided you can create a matching ground truth output

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that it's as you say -- your model is learning some pattern in your systematic padding and using it at inference time.

##### New Padding Approach

---

My first instinct is to use mirror padding (assuming there is some spatial correlation that is invariant to left-right reflection). This would (in principle) no longer make the padding neutral or even constant, but might alleviate the issue by preventing an abnormal bias in the "pixels" near the edges. Mirror padding "reflects" an input along its borders to expand the input while maintaining continuity of the input. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvQFq.png is an example of a 2 dimensional padding approach, but you may only need a 1 dimensional pad. (Image source: [Image padding with reflect (mirror) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826703/image-padding-with-reflect-mirror-in-python))

Another known padding approach is wrap-around padding, which would work better than mirror padding if your input is spatially periodic. (see the right half of https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijae/2022/9873112/fig5/ , the paper is mostly irrelevant)

##### Simple Data Augmentation

---

And as @Yakov Dan proposed, it's probably a good idea to randomize the padding to prevent the model from learning it (e.g. distribute padding columns randomly on either side of your image). This effectively "noises" the part of the receptive field that you systematically padded before in deeper neurons with a large receptive field.

It may also be reasonable to combine the approaches, perhaps by splitting the padding columns randomly on either side of a small input and then maybe applying mirror padding to those pixels.

The proposition of mirror and circular (wrap-around) padding is also supported by the "blind spot" findings in https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02178